# Evaluation of function AVERAGE caused a divide by zero error

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula

In `Google sheets`, I just input the following values through `Data Validation`.

[image: Data Validation Values]

Once the range of values are input in a `google sheet`, it looks like the following:

[image: Data range values in cell]

From the above figure:

I want to take an average of inputted drop down values in the range between
`B6 and B14`.

I applied a formula `=Average(B6,B14)`. But, it display error message.

Error!

```
Evaluation of function AVERAGE caused a divide by zero error.
```

Anyone knows how to resolve it. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following formula:

```
=AVERAGE(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(B6:B14, "\d+")*1))
```

#### Explanation

The [`=REGEXTRACT()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en) function will extract the first match of a [regular expression](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754#regular_expression) for the given string. In this case, the first chain of numbers will be extracted.

Afterwards, the result of the function is multiplied by 1. This is done to transform the type of the result of [`=REGEXTRACT()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en) from a string to a number, so that we may afterwards calculate the average.

[`=REGEXTRACT()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en), by default, operates on single strings - but not on multiple cells at the same time. For that reason, we have to wrap the call with [`=ARRAYFORMULA()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) which will allow to call it with a range as a parameter.

Finally, the [`=AVERAGE()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093615?hl=en) function is called.

#### Handling empty cells

With the previous response, given a range in which at least a cell is empty/doesn't conform the regex specified in the [`=REGEXTRACT()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en) call, an error will be returned. We have two main options to handle this situation:

1. Ignore the cell. The cell will be completely ignored for the average computation:

   ```
   =AVERAGE(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B6:B14, "\d+")*1, "")))
   ```
2. Treat the cell as a `0` towards the average computation.

   ```
   =AVERAGE(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B6:B14, "\d+")*1, 0)))
   ```

Both the solutions use the [`=IFERROR()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en) function. In case the call to [`=REGEXTRACT()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en) returns an error, the value will be replaced respectively for an empty string (which doesn't count in the average computation) or for a 0 instead.

Answer (score 0):

use this fx:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B6:B14; "\d+")*1)))
```

Comment: Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "\d+" does not match text of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 value "". Now I am getting this after applying your formula.

Comment: you will need to use `=ARRAYFORMULA` to use `=REGEXTRACT` over a range of cells. Try this modification instead: `=AVERAGE(ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(B6:B14, "\d+")*1))`

Comment: @carlesgg97 You are correct. You made the day. It worked like a charm! Thank you.

Comment: @carlesgg97 What if i give empty value between B6 and B14?

Comment: @DeepakKeynes In that case you can use the [`=IFERROR()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en) formula to handle this case. If you want the value to not be counted at all towards the calculation, you can use `=AVERAGE(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B6:B14, "\d+")*1,"")))`. If you want it to be counted as 0 instead, try `=AVERAGE(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(B6:B14, "\d+")*1,0)))`. Cheers

Comment: Hey @carlesgg97 You can edit the above answer or you could post a new one.